# Extending Zend View Helper Placeholder

Tags: php, zend-framework, placeholder, zend-view

I was reading the manual about [basic placeholder usage](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/learning.view.placeholders.basics.html), and it has this example:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    // ...

    protected function _initSidebar()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('View');
        $view = $this->getResource('View');

        $view->placeholder('sidebar')
             // "prefix" -> markup to emit once before all items in collection
             ->setPrefix("<div class=\"sidebar\">\n    <div class=\"block\">\n")
             // "separator" -> markup to emit between items in a collection
             ->setSeparator("</div>\n    <div class=\"block\">\n")
             // "postfix" -> markup to emit once after all items in a collection
             ->setPostfix("</div>\n</div>");
    }

    // ...
}
```

I want to accomplish almost exactly that, but I'd like to conditionally add more class values to the repeating `div`s, at time of rendering if possible, when all the content is in the placeholder. One thing I specifically want to do is add the class of "first" to the first element and "last" to the last element. I assume that I'll have to extend the `Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder` class to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string set with `setSeparator()` is what will be used to implode elements in a container. Either set it to an empty string or just leave out the call to `setSeparator()` and insert the separating divs along with your other content:

```
  <?php $this->placeholder('sidebar')->captureStart(); ?>

  <?php if($userIsAdmin === TRUE) { ?>

      <div class="block admin-menu">
        <h4>User Administration</h4>
        <ul>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 

  <?php } ?>

      <div class="block other-stuff">      
          <h4>Non-Admin Stuff</h4>
          <ul>
              <li> ... </li>
              <li> ... </li>
          </ul>
       </div>

  <?php $this->placeholder('sidebar')->captureEnd() ?>
```

Comment: I actually want to set classes at time of rendering if possible, when all the content is in the placeholder. One thing I specifically want to do is add the class of "first" to the first element and "last" to the last element. (Updating question with these requirements as well)

Comment: I ended up using your solution, so I'm awarding it as the answer. Thanks Gordon!